# Would a dense city impact the radius of a nuclear bomb?

Tags: nuclear-physics, thermal-radiation, explosions

There’s plenty of sites out there where you can choose a nuclear bomb, pick a location, and see the radius of destruction.

I noticed that the radius size of a bomb dropped in the heart of NYC is illustrated as being the same size as if the same bomb was dropped in plains - flat land with no large obstructions (buildings, mountains, etc.)

Is it the case that cities densely packed with buildings wouldn’t changed the various damage radii of a nuclear weapon?

Comment: Nuclear weapons are typically detonated from some height, not ground level.

Comment: Historically most have been detonated underground. But that was testing…

Answer (score 1):

To make an order-of-magnitude estimate of this effect, model the blast as a sphere and compare the volume occupied by “complicated” skyscraper topography with the volume of the blast sphere.

If you imagine a “block-buster” conventional explosive, whose blast radius is roughly the size of a city block, it is reasonable to imagine you could substantially shadow such an explosion with a building that is also the size of a city block.  But if the blast radius is measured in kilometers, an obstacle a hundred meters across is going to occupy a *much* smaller fraction of the zone of destruction, leaving more destruction available for everyone else.

Note that most discussions of nuclear explosions are of “airburst” explosions at some altitude, so that the primary blast direction is “down” rather than “sideways” in most of the target area.